# How do I find if a page has a template?

Tags: query, page-template, meta-query

So I'm doing a query like this:

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'homepage', 'meta_value' => 'yes', 
'post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'modified', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) );
```

To get a single page with a specific key value, how do I get the page template from a query like this, if it has one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick for you.  This shows what template file is stored in `post_meta`, if one has been selected in the admin panel:

`$template_name = get_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );`

If you want to see if the page is the homepage, use `is_home()` or `is_front_page()`.

If you want to see what files are generating the page, use this in your functions.php:

```
// Returns a list of files used to generate the page.  Best called in footer.php before </body>
function _dump_files()
{
    # @todo Aufrufende Datei kann im Array manchmal fehlen!
    add_action( 'all', create_function( '', "echo '<pre>'; print_r( get_included_files() ); echo '</pre>'; return;" ) );
}
```

I use it in `footer.php` like this:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    _dump_files() ;
}
```

Comment: The `debug_backtrace` does not seem to take into account some of WordPress's idiosyncrasies ( so it does not actually tell you all files that are called) but it will tell you the current template file. Also the above function can be shortened by simply putting `debug_print_backtrace();` in your footer wrapped in pre tags.

Comment: There's a number of files missing, but template-wise (if called in `footer.php`), it calls everything but `header.php`.  That's not perfect, but I'm not really sure if it's possible to get a full backtrace in WP.  The main reason I use this one is because I like having the `<hr />` between the lines - personal preference.

Comment: Added a more functional full backtrace per @kaiser in WPSE Chat, generates all files used from start to finish.

Comment: Not that I care much in this case, but I'd please you to not update answers here with stuff I give you in chat without asking before. This site is under a license, where code that's shared on chat not is.

Answer (score 1):

One quick method I use is the WordPress global `$template`. I output it in the page source as well.

Just before the closing `</body>` tag
`global $template;

  echo '<!-- the template is:' . $template . '-->';`

or as a function:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'show_template');
function show_template() {
    global $template;
    echo '<!-- the template is:' . $template . '-->';
}
```